# How to read input from tkinter Entry in jupyter notebook python

Tags: tkinter

[image: My GUI Form]

> I am trying the read the Input Entered in Ticker Entry and analyze later in the code. But for now, I am simply trying to read input from Ticker and Insert the same value into label Current price. Followed is my code. and I am getting the error for which I attached the screen shot. [image]

```
daily_heading = Label(top, text = "Daily Analysis").place(x = 0, y = 20)  
intra_day_heading = Label(top, text = "Intraday  Analysis").place(x = 330,y = 20)   

daily_analysis = Button(top,text = "Daily Analysis", command=insert_data).place(x = 30,y = 670)
```

intraday_analysis = Button(top,text = "Intraday Analysis").place(x = 330,y = 670)

```
def insert_data():
   print("You enterted followed symbol")
   symbol = str(top.user_name_input_area.get())
   print(symbol)
   #top.current_price_input_area.insert(0, symbol)
```

Comment: Entire code is here...

Comment: Better provide a [mre].

Comment: here is the minimal code.

Comment: But the code cannot reproduce the issue.  What is `top`? What is `user_name_input_area`? etc.